# AWS ECS Fargate Service Deployment Failure and Health Check Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer, health-check

Experiencing deployment failures with my ECS Fargate service. Initially ran smoothly, but now fails consistently during pipeline deployment. Health checks also show discrepancies - returning 403 despite successful tests with Postman/Curl. Recently, service stopped running, and both ALB and TG were deleted.

Reviewed logs= no errors
Tested health checks manually= returning ok, until TG was deleted

Comment: Have you tried deactivating the health check. If the deployment is working fine you will know it is coming from your health check. HTTP 403 means forbidden, usually returned when there's no controller associated with this URL.

Comment: Created a new service to test without health check and it was successful.I am  thinking there might be a problem with health check endpoint mapped in HomeController

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok clearly you isolated your problem. 
Could you describe how you implemented your service (language, framework, ...), how you are testing it (the exact curl instruction), the task descriptor including the health check definition).

Comment: Language: Java
Framework: Spring Boot
Description: The service is a simple discount service implemented using Java with the Spring Boot framework.

Comment: HealthCheck:
    Path:  /health-check
    Port: 80
    Protocol: HTTP
    TimeoutSeconds: 5
    IntervalSeconds: 30
    UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
    HealthyThresholdCount: 2

Comment: curl -X GET https://discount.cgseerapps.com/discount-service/health-check spotted an error in the logs today (invalid character found in method name)

Comment: Realised I had to add the context path to the health check path define in the target group (stopped getting the 404 response after)